# If $a$ is a sum of squares then there exists an element whose norm is $-1$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

This is part of a question(2.9.3) from Patrick Morandi's "Field and Galois Theory"
I am just plain stuck on this fact:

> $F(\sqrt{a})/F$ is a field extension where $a\in F-F^2$ and $F$ does not contain a primitive fourth root of unity. 
>   If $a$ is a sum of two squares in $F$, prove that $N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}(\alpha)=-1$ for some $\alpha\in F(\sqrt{a})$ and that $N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}(\alpha)=a$ for some $\alpha\in F(\sqrt{a})$. Hence, show that $N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}(b)\equiv a \mod F^{*2}$ for some $b\in F(\sqrt{a})$.

I know that $\text{Gal}(F(\sqrt{a})/F=\{1,\sigma\}$ where $\sigma:\sqrt{a}\mapsto-\sqrt{a}$. Also, $\{1,\sqrt{a}\}$ is a basis for $F(\sqrt{a})$ over $F$, so the norm of any element $c_1+c_2\sqrt{a}\in F(\sqrt{a})$ is just $\left(c_1+c_2\sqrt{a}\right)\left(c_1-c_2\sqrt{a}\right)=c_1^2-c_2^2a$.

The fact that the norm map is surjective when $F$ is a finite field gives us the first two facts right away.
But it has nothing to do with $a$ being a sum of squares, or that $F$ has no fourth root of unity, and of course it only works for finite fields.

Also, if you compute $\min(\sqrt{a-1},F)=x^2-a-1$, then $N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}=(-1)^n(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}=-1$ since $n=[F(\sqrt{a}):F]=2$.
but this also seems wrong because it still has nothing to do with the premises.

How might I proceed here?

Comment: $\sqrt{a-1}$ is not in your field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a = u^2+v^2, \qquad N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}(\frac{u+\sqrt{a}}{v}) =\frac{u+\sqrt{a}}{v}\frac{u-\sqrt{a}}{v}= \frac{u^2-a}{v^2} =-1,\\ \qquad N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}(\sqrt{a}\frac{u+\sqrt{a}}{v}) = - N_{F(\sqrt{a})/F}(\sqrt{a}) = a$$

Answer (score 1):

Your notations are a bit shaky: $L$ is not defined, although it should naturally mean $F(\sqrt a)$ ; in the first question, the two $\alpha$ should not be the same. This being said, $a$ is a sum of squares in $F$ iff $a$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt {-1})$ (which is a quadratic extension of $F$ by hypothesis), and the latter condition is plainly equivalent to $-1$ being a norm from $F(\sqrt a)$. Since $-a$ is already a norm from $F(\sqrt a)$, so will be $a$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why $a$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt{-1})$ is equivalent to $-1$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt{a})$?

Comment: This is a classical property of quaternion algebras. Given any field $F$ of characteristic $\neq 2$, for any $a, b \in  F$,$a$  is a norm from $F(\sqrt b)$ iff $b$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt b)$. The (elementary) proof goes through the exisence of a zero for the $X^2 - aY^2 -bZ^2$ , see e.g. exercise 4.3 in Cassels- Fröhlich's ANT. A detailed solution  is given in prop. 1.17 of Gille-Samuelzy's "Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology" .

Comment: Misprint : $a$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt b)$ iff $b$ is a norm from $F(\sqrt a)$