# $a$ is a norm in $K(\sqrt{a})/K$ if and only if it is the sum of two squares

Tags: field-theory, solution-verification

> $a$ is a norm in a quadratic extension $K(\sqrt{a})/K$ if and only if $a=u^2+v^2$ for some $u,v\in K$. $K$ an arbitrary field.

Only if follows from:

[If $a$ is a sum of squares then there exists an element whose norm is $-1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318845/if-a-is-a-sum-of-squares-then-there-exists-an-element-whose-norm-is-1?fbclid=IwAR3HQdZdJB06AH9gyqBGxmePQ5CTIktK9MgM2hiqAl5dnA09_axW4Bk5nJM)

But for the other, using the equivalent condition: $-1$ is the norm of an element, I obtain that 
$$-1=x^2-ay^2$$
$$x^2+1=ay^2$$
for some $x,y\in K$.
So if I had the conditions in the link attached, i.e. that $K$ does not contain $i=\sqrt{-1}$, then the problem would follow immediately. But for the theorem in which this shows up I'm trying to verify the proof, there are no conditions on $K$.

Edit: I think I figured out a positive solution, for $char\neq 2$

Suppose $i\in K$. Then $(a+1)^2-(a-1)^2=4a$. Then, we have that 
$$(\frac{a+1}{2})^2-(\frac{a-1}{2})^2=a$$
and since $i\in K$,
$$(\frac{a+1}{2})^2+(i\frac{a-1}{2})^2=a.$$

So I've reduced the problem to checking for characteristic $2$.

Edit 2:

But in the field extension $\mathbb{F}_2(t)/\mathbb{F}_2(t^2)$ ($t$ a transcendental element), $t^2$ is not the sum of two squares, since that would be

$$t^2=a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2$$

Which implies that

$t\in\mathbb{F}_2(t^2)$. So we need for $char K\neq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $i\in K$, and $K$ does not have characteristic two
then every element of $K$ is a sum of two squares.

Let $a\in K$. Then there is a solution to the simultaneous equations
\begin{align}
x+iy&=a\\
x-iy&=1
\end{align}
and then
$$x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)=a.$$

Comment: In characteristic $2$, a solution to the system implies $a=1$ though?